# how to use tf.scatter_nd "without" accumulation?

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say I have a (None, 2)-shape tensor `indices`, and (None,)-shape tensor `values`. These actual row # and values will be determined at runtime.

I would like to set a 4x5 tensor `t` that each element of indices has values of values. I found that I can use tf.scatter_nd like this:

```
t = tf.scatter_np(indices, values, [4, 5])
# E.g., indices = [[1,2],[2,3]], values = [100, 200] 
# t[1,2] <-- 100; t[2,3] <-- 200
```

My problem is that: when indices has duplicates, the values will be accumulated.

```
# E.g., indices = [[1,2],[1,2]], values = [100, 200]  
# t[1,2] <-- 300
```

I would like to assign only one, i,e, either ignorance (so, the first value) or overwriting (so, the last value).

I feel like I need to check duplicates in indices, or I need to use tensorflow loop. Could anyone please advise? (hopefully a minimal example code?)

Comment: There is `tf.unique`. You would need to convert your indices with `i1 + size1*i2`, then back using modulo. There is probably a smarter way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tf.unique`: the only issue is that this op requires a 1D tensor.
Thus, to overcome this I decided to use the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).
In short, it exists a bijective function that maps a tuple (in this case a pair of values, but it works for any N-dimensional tuple) to a single value.

Once the coordinates have been reduced to a 1-D tensor of scalar, then `tf.unique` can be used to find the indices of the unique numbers.

The Cantor pairing function is invertible, thus now we know not only the indices of the non-repeated values within the 1-D tensor, but we can also go back to the 2-D space of the coordinates and use `scatter_nd` to perform the update without the problem of the accumulator.

### TL;DR:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Dummy values
indices = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]])
values = np.array([100, 200])

# Placeholders
indices_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(2, 2))
values_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2))

# Use the Cantor tuple to create a one-to-one correspondence between the coordinates
# and a single value
x = tf.cast(indices_[:, 0], tf.float32)
y = tf.cast(indices_[:, 1], tf.float32)
z = (x + y) * (x + y + 1) / 2 + y  # shape = (2)

# Collect unique indices, treated as single values
# Drop the indices position into z because are useless
unique_cantor, _ = tf.unique(z)

# Go back from cantor numbers to pairs of values
w = tf.floor((tf.sqrt(8 * unique_cantor + 1) - 1) / 2)
t = (tf.pow(w, 2) + w) / 2
y = z - t
x = w - y

# Recreate a batch of coordinates that are uniques
unique_indices = tf.cast(tf.stack([x, y], axis=1), tf.int32)

# Update without accumulator
go = tf.scatter_nd(unique_indices, values_, [4, 5])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(go, feed_dict={indices_: indices, values_: values}))
```

Comment: Thanks, @nessuno! I would like to cast 100 votes to this!

Comment: lol, no problem. You're welcome (moreover I guess that's overcomplicated, for sure exists a better solution)

Comment: Hi, @nessumo, I found some errors: (1)  `unique_cantor` was never used. (2) `w` instead of '2' as in `t = (tf.pow(w, 2) + w) / 2`. (3) due to floating numbers, I had to use `unique_indices = tf.cast(tf.round(tf.stack([x, y], axis=1)), tf.int32)`. In addition, if I get the filtered `unique_indices`, how can I get corresponding 'values_` ?

Comment: Oops! I copy-pasted the wrong script! I update the answer. However, yes, The updated answer contains the right formula (w is a function of unique_cantor and not of z and t has a w instead of 2). The rounding shouldn't be necessary, the cantor mapping should work well just converting the type from float to int32

Comment: Thanks for your response, @nessuno. Btw, shouldn't `y = z -  t` be `y = unique_cantor - t` since here we are still converting back from `unique_cantor`. Also, I guess we need to remove relevant elements in `values_`. Would you try `indices = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [1,2]]); values = np.array([100, 200, 300])`? (I finally had my own version, but I am curious how you would resolve this.)

Answer (score 2):

Apply tf.scatter_nd also to a matrix of ones. That will give you the number of elements that are accumulated and you can just divide your result by that to get an average. (But watch out for zeros, for those you should divide by one).

```
counter = tf.ones(tf.shape(values))
t = tf.scatter_nd(indices,values,shape)
t_counter = tf.scatter_nd(indices,counter,shape)
```

Then divide t by t_counter (but only where t_counter is not zero).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution, I used [`tf.unsorted_segment_max`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unsorted_segment_max)  to avoid accumulation

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # #########
    # Examples:
    # ##########
    width, height, depth = [3, 3, 2]
    indices = tf.cast([[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]], tf.int32)
    values  = tf.cast([1, 2, 3], tf.int32)

    # ########################
    # Filter duplicated indices
    # #########################
    flatten = tf.matmul(indices, [[height * depth], [depth], [1]])
    filtered, idx = tf.unique(tf.squeeze(flatten))

    # #####################
    # Obtain updated result
    # #####################
    def reverse(index):
        """Map from 1-D to 3-D """
        x = index / (height * depth)
        y = (index - x * height * depth) / depth
        z = index - x * height * depth - y * depth
        return tf.stack([x, y, z], -1)        

    # This will pick the maximum value instead of accumulating the result
    updated_values  = tf.unsorted_segment_max(values, idx, tf.shape(filtered_idx)[0])
    updated_indices = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda i: reverse(i), elems=filtered)

    # Now you can scatter_nd without accumulation
    result = tf.scatter_nd(updated_indices, 
                           updated_values, 
                           tf.TensorShape([3, 3, 2]))
```